# How do you set the NavigationToolbar2TkAgg's background to a certain color in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I've been developing a graphing program and I'm wondering if it is possible to add something of a facecolor attribute to the toolbar, since it is not on the figure

```
    self.g = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100, facecolor=self.controller.color)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.g, self)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self)
    self.toolbar.facecolor = self.controller.color
```

Comment: Which module is `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` from?

Comment: matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg is the module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tk widgets have a property `background`, which denoted their background color. You may set this to the toolbar itself, and also for the message box setting the coordinates.

```
color = "#d469a3"
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root,  )
toolbar.config(background=color)
toolbar._message_label.config(background=color)
toolbar.update()
```

Some complete example, based on [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html).

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


color = "#d469a3"
f = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100, facecolor=color)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t, s)


# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root,  )
toolbar.config(background=color)
toolbar._message_label.config(background=color)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

You may also change the button color,

```
for button in toolbar.winfo_children():
    button.config(background=color)
```

resulting in

[image]

*Note: In newer versions of matplotlib you should use `NavigationToolbar2Tk` instead of `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`.*

Comment: There is a small white border around the buttons now, what do I do if I want to get rid of it?

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't meaning that, but it helped me figure out the problem. Tkinter (when using it on mac) adds a small border, so for me the solution was to set the 'highlightbackground' attribute to the color I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you coloring the toolbar in black it might causes the icons to be almost invisible like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEwAc.png

I faced a similar problem and discovered a solution in this conversation: (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22150/). To improve visibility, try this modification:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.tk_setPalette(background="black", selectColor="midnight blue", foreground="white")
```

After applying this fix, the icons should be clearly visible as demonstrated in the updated image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/loQSN.png